# Jquery: Loading an HTML page and then another html page via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, delay, timedelay

```
  //when document loads
   $(document).ready(function() {

    //navigation item is clicked
     $('.nav_item').click(function() {

    //get the clicked nav items id
    var nav_item = $(this).attr("id");
    var location_to_load = nav_item + '.html';

   //load the loading html then the page
   $('#sliding_content_container').load('loading.html', null, showResponse);

   //load the page
   function showResponse(){
    $('#sliding_content_container').delay(900).load(location_to_load);
   };

   //dont refresh
   return false;
   }); 
   });
```

Hey, I'm learning Jquery and just wondered why I can't call a "loading page" and then the destination with a delay, it seems everything I try doesn't work for instance adding .delay on or chaining the functions..

any help will be great, I'm giving jquery a good old crack.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`delay` method](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) is used for animations.
It adds a delay item to the animation queue, delaying any *animations* called after it.
It will not affect normal methods.

Instead, you should call the [`setTimeout` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout), like this:

```
$('#sliding_content_container').load('loading.html', null, function() {
    setTimeout(function() { 
        $('#sliding_content_container').load(location_to_load);
    }, 900);
});
```

Comment: +1 for setTimeout, but ----------------- Why do you still have a `.delay(900)` in there?

Answer (score 0):

For delay to work, you need to use the queue for your next call to load in `showResponse()`.

```
function showResponse(){
    $('#sliding_content_container')
      .delay(900)
      .queue(
        function()
        {
          var $this = $(this);
          $this
            .load(
              location_to_load,
              false,
              function()
              {
                $this.dequeue();
              }
            );
        }
      );
};
```

If you want to, you can also use a queue other than 'fx', in case it bugs you that this queue is usually used for animations.

Comment: This works (though a bit overkill), but you can do it in a much more concise way: `.queue(function(n) { $(this).load(location_to_load, n); });`

Answer (score -1):

It's normal, that you cannot delay it with .delay();
AJAX is asynchronous by default (sometimes it helps to check what abbreviation of technology means).
It's quite a lot of time since I used jQuery, but as far as i remember .ajax request should be suitable.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: You are misunderstanding his problem.

Comment: thanks for your reply, much appreciated aswell -I've had a good read now and see my problem.